# How to fix a proof of Dini's Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

I am aware of 2 proofs of Dini. One is by contradiction and Bolzano-Weierstrass, and one is by an open covers definition. I decided to try to make a 'direct' proof without using 'every open cover has a finite subcover', but I struggle to finish it. For reference:

> (Dini) Suppose $F_n,F:[a,b]→ℝ$ are continuous functions such that for every $x∈[a,b]$, $F_n(x)\downarrow F(x)$ as $n→∞$. Prove that in fact, $F_n → F$ uniformly.

Note first that without loss, $F=0$ and $F_n\geq 0$. I want to argue that I can control $|F_n(x) - F_n(y)| ≤ ω(|x-y|)$ with a modulus of continuity $ω$ **independent of $n$**; using this I can then create a grid of points $(a_i)$ $δ/2$ apart so that $ω(δ)<ε$, and choose an $M$ so that for $m>M$, $\sup_i F_m(a_{i})<ε $,  then conclude via 
$$ F_m(x) ≤ F_m(a_{i,x}) + |F_m(a_{i,x}) - F_m(x)| ≤ \sup_i F_m(a_{i}) +ω(δ) < 2ε $$
where $a_{i,x}$ is some $a_i$ close to $x$.

I unfortunately don't see how to prove that $ω$ can be chosen independently of $n$; is this possible?

Comment: Consider this question: Can you prove the same statement about $(a,b)$ instead of $[a, b]$? (Hint: $F_n(x) = x^n$ on $(0,1)$.) So, what is it about $[a,b]$ that makes it work?

Comment: @PaulSinclair clearly its the compactness. I have tried to use boundedness by making a grid....so I have to use that its closed somewhere?

Comment: I certainly can't compete with an author of text books on the subject, but yes, my point was that you need to bring in the compactness - not just closed and bounded, but the properties of compactness that they imply. To show that $\omega$ can be choses independently of $n$ requires a compactness argument equivalent to those in the other proofs.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I suppose this is too vague to be answerable as a separate MSE question, but I was hoping that there would be a way to translate compactness arguments into a layman's 'closed and bounded' argument. I was motivated to try this proof method due to a similar result for complex analytic functions but there the magic of Cauchy's integral formula easily gives us a uniform modulus $ω$. Also, i forgot to say thanks for pointing out that I had not yet used compactness :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[Continued: ... indulge me.]***

There is   agreement now that this question is really about Dini's theorem and compactness arguments.
 Mr. Khor wanted to try for a proof based on using a single modulus of continuity for the whole sequence,
 not to avoid compactness arguments--just for a different perspective.

I think all proofs of Dini's theorem look the same when you stare long enough, so his proposed proof might shift that perspective around, but 
 it won't be very radical.

The big four compactness arguments on the real line [HB, BW, Cousin-coverings (CC), nested-intervals (NI)]
 are the major tools one learns in a first course.  BW generalizes to compact metric spaces and HB to compact
 topological spaces, but CC and NI don't survive past $\mathbb{R}^n$.

There are two more "compactness arguments" on the real line, although I would describe them more as "*back-to-basics*."
 For completeness I will sketch them here.  These arguments are quite nice when they can be used, but don't expect all problems to
 offer a tidy way of using them.  Keep HB, BW, etc. handy.

> **Theorem (Dini)** Suppose $F_n:  a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$  are continuous
>   functions decreasing pointwise to zero. Then the convergence is
>   uniform.

***Proof using monotone-convergence property:*** Let $\epsilon>0$.  We claim we can find an integer $M$ so that $|F_M(x)|<\epsilon$
 for all $a\leq x \leq b$  and that would prove the theorem.

Let $x_0=a$, select the first integer $N_0$ so that $F_{N_0}(x_0)< \epsilon$.  If $N_0$ doesn't work for our $M$ then there is an $x_1>x_0$ so that $F_{N_0}(x )<\epsilon$
 for all $x_0\leq x<x_1$ and $F_{N_0}(x_1)=\epsilon$.
 (This by continuity.)  Now choose $N_1$ the same way,
 as the first integer with $F_{N_0}(x_0)< \epsilon$. Etc.

Do this inductively and within a finite number of steps we reach an integer $N_k$ that we can take as our $M$.  If not then we have two increasing sequences $\{x_k\} $
 and $\{N_k\}$, the first bounded and the second has $N_k\to \infty$.

By the monotone-convergence property $\lim_{k\to \infty}x_k=z$ exists and $a<z\leq b$.  By the same arguments we have seen repeatedly, there is a first  $N$ so that $F_N(z)<\epsilon$ and a contradiction is easily deduced.

***Proof using least upper bound property:*** Let $\epsilon>0$.
  We claim we can find an integer $M$ so that $|F_M(x)|<\epsilon$
  for all $a\leq x \leq b$  and that would prove the theorem.

Define $S$ as the set of all points $s\in [a,b]$ such that
   there is an integer $N$ (which may depend on $s$) so that for every  $a\leq t \leq s$ the inequality $F_N(t)<\epsilon$
   must hold.  Argue (i) $S$ is nonempty and bounded.     (ii)  Define $z=\sup S$.  (iii)  Prove that $z\in S$.
   (iv) Prove that $z<b$ is impossible.

[We are using the  least upper bound property to obtain (ii).  I prefer to call it the *last point argument*, since we are imagining there is a *last point* $z$ beyond which we cannot prove the statement that we want to prove.]

The same details that worked before are used to prove (i), (iii), and (iv) [as expected of course].

---

**A more general point of view on Dini's theorem.**

For fans of Dini's theorem there is another way of looking at the proof that, I think, clarfies what is going on.  Use this definition and theorem.

> **Definition**  Let $F$, $F_n$ be real-valued functions defined on
>   $\mathbb{R}$.  We say $F_n\to F$ *uniformly locally* at a point $x$ if,
>   for every $\epsilon>0$ there is an integer $N$ and  $\delta>0$ so that
>   $$ |F_n(t)-F(t)|< \epsilon $$    for all $n\geq N$  and all
>   $|t-x|<\delta$.
>
> **Theorem**  Let $F$, $F_n$ be real-valued functions defined on
>   $\mathbb{R}$.  Suppose that $F_n\to F$ uniformly locally at every
>   point $x$ in a compact set $K$.  Then $F_n\to F$ uniformly on $K$.

Now what is Dini's theorem?  Under the assumptions of Dini's theorem all functions are continuous on a compact interval $[a,b]$  and the convergence is monotone and pointwise to $F$.  Just show, quickly, that in that case     $F_n\to F$ uniformly locally at every point $x$ in $[a,b]$ and apply the theorem. While Dini's theorem seems to be about continuity and monotonic convergence it just happens to be a local uniform condition.  All compactness arguments are about going from the local to the global and that is all that is happening here.

Comment: While I didnt get quite what I asked for, the monotone convergence property in particular I feel is very much in the same spirit as my attempt, and will accept this as an answer. Thanks for the many proofs :)

Comment: I enjoyed your creativity in trying this direction.  That is rather more what the profession is about than just nailing one proof on the wall and declaring it to be the definitive one.

Answer (score 5):

Don't have any ideas on your proposed proof, other than that already suggested by Mr. Sinclair, namely that whatever argument you use will certainly 
 invoke compactness.

What I can do is add to your collection of proofs.  You know a Bolzano-Weierstrass argument and   Heine-Borel argument for Dini's theorem.
 In Exercise 9.4.7 [Elementary Real Analysis](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/com/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Landscape.pdf) I proposed as a problem constructing proofs based on the other compactness arguments.  I don't recall what I had in mind but maybe it is time to do it myself.

I think of *Heine-Borel* as the tool for serious scholars who dislike inelegance and distrust anything that can not be generalized to extremes.
  *Bolzano-Weierstrass* is more get-your-hands-dirty and should appeal to engineers and plumbers.  *Cousin's covering lemma*  is, because of its Belgian origin,
  more effete and esoteric, with suggestions of Hercule Poirot, absinthe, Balkan Sobranies in long  cigarette holders, etc.
 The *nested interval argument* is just down on the farm, basic, get-the-work done attitude.  So, for your collection, here are the other proofs.

> **Theorem** **(Dini)** Suppose $F_n:[a,b] \to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous
>   functions decreasing pointwise to zero.  Then the convergence is
>   uniform.

***Proof using Cousin coverings***: Let
  $\epsilon>0$.  Define 
 $\mathcal{C}$ as the collection of all subintervals $[u,v]$ of $[a,b]$ with the property that, for some integer $n$
 ($n=n(u,v)$) it is true that $F_n(x)< \epsilon$ for all
 $u\leq x \leq v$.  This collection  $\mathcal{C}$ is a full cover in the Cousin sense, since if $x\in [a,b]$ there is an integer
 $n$ so that $F_n(x)<\epsilon$ and so, by continuity a positive
 $\delta$ with $F_n(t)<\epsilon$ for all $|t-x|<\delta$.  Thus all closed subintervals of $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ belong to  $\mathcal{C}$ .

By Cousin's lemma there is a partition $\{[u_i,v_i];i=1,2,\dots,n\}$ of $[a,b]$ contained in  $\mathcal{C}$ .
 Take $N=\max\{n(u_i,v_i):i=1,2,\dots, n\}$ and any point $x$.  Select the interval  $[u_i,v_i]$ to which $x$ belongs and check that
$$  F_m(x)\leq F_{n(u_i,v_i)}(x)<\epsilon$$ for all $m\geq N$.

***Proof using a nested sequence of intervals:***
If the convergence is not uniform then there is a $\epsilon_0>0$ so that the following statement is true:

> For infinitely many $n$ the inequality $f_n(x) < \epsilon _0$  fails
>   at some point $x\in [a,b]$ which may depend on $n$.

Split the interval into two equal halves and choose $[a_1,b_1]$ as the half for which this is true:

> For infinitely many $n$ the inequality $f_n(x) < \epsilon _0$  fails
>   at some point $x\in [a_1,b_1]$ which may depend on $n$.

A standard nested sequence of intervals is defined by induction and this shrinks to a single point $z$ in $[a,b]$.  We know
that $F_N(z)< \epsilon_0$ for some $N$ and so, by continuity there  is a positive
$\delta$ with $F_N(t)<\epsilon_0$ for all $|t-x|<\delta$. 
For large enough $M$ the interval $[a_M,b_M] \subset(z-\delta,z+\delta)$ and one has, for all $t$ in the interval $[a_M,b_M]$, that
$$ F_n(t)\leq F_N(t) < \epsilon_0$$
for all $n$ greater than both $M$ and $N$.  This contradicts the choice of interval $[a_M,b_M]$.  The contradiction completes the proof.

Comment: Thanks for your very nice answer (and your books which I stumbled upon as an undergrad). I feel like my attempt only runs around in circles but I'll give it another go tonight!